# Not all divs appearing as full width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to alter the footer of my site and for some reason, only some of the divs are showing as full width: https://www.lpp-leicester.org.uk/. You can see that the light blue div and the dark grey div are showing correctly as full width but the rest of the footer has a white margin.

I am very much a novice at any kind of coding so I'm possibly missing something obvious.

I wasn't sure what code to include with this question, short of pasting my entire footer file but here goes...

```
<div class="container">

            <div class="row justify-content-center">

                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/jvj.png" style="height:130px">

            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">

                <div class="col-sm-9" >

                    <div class="menuborder">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <p style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; "><a style="text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;color:#32373C !important;" href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></p>
                            </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                 <p style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; "><a style="text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;color:#32373C!important;" href="/contact/"> Contact Us</a></p>                               
                            </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                 <p style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; "><a style="text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;color:#32373C!important;" href="/faq/">FAQ</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:1em;">
                            <p style="text-align: center; color:#32373C">© Copyright Leicester Primary Partnership 2019 | This site is maintained by the <a style="color:#32373C !important; text-decoration:underline !important;" href="https://www.sdsa.net/">School Development Support Agency</a><p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're setting a container which is adding margins.

You should use your code like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="fullwidth-blue">
        inner content
    </div>
</div>
```

To keep your image centered add

```css
.fullwidth-blue{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for your response - I have removed the container and my div is now full-width but my image is no longer centered!

Comment: Add text-align: center; to your .fullwidth-blue css

Comment: images in boostrap4 have their class to make it centered and the structure is container > row > col, shouldn't be putting an image inside row. See my answer

Comment: that's a wrong bootstrap grid, the grid says row > col > [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/] ...

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for you is to add the `row` class to your `fullwidth-blue` div

I just did that in the browser Dev Tools and it worked right away.

So:

```
<div class="row fullwidth-blue">
... // your footer code
</div>
```

Comment: Hi peadar, thanks so much for your answer - I have made the addition that you have suggested and it has partially worked - now I only have a white margin on one side?

Comment: As @rob.m says below I think removing the width 100% on *.fullwidth-blue* will solve this.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi peader, unfortunately when I remove the full width 100% then it breaks it completely. I have managed to get the div full width but now my image refuses to center!

Comment: @maestroveale see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are using a flud/flex grid system where you have to add `row` classes. Your `fullwidth-blue` container doesn't have this class. Just add it and it works.

```
<div class="row fullwidth-blue">
```

Edit: Your `width: 100%;` breaks the style. Just remove it from the element.

```
.fullwidth-blue {
    background-color: #8b9694;
}
```

Comment: Hi insomnia, thanks so much for your answer - I have made the addition that you have suggested and it has partially worked - now I only have a white margin on one side.

Comment: Hi insomnia, unfortunately if I remove the full width 100% then it full-on breaks it. I have managed to get the div full-width now but I am now struggling to centre my image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your container "container-fluid" has a padding of 15px on left and right, which is counterbalanced in your child divs by a "margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px" (found in the class "row"). Since your footer div does not inherit from this class, and is also a child of "container-fluid" the borders you see are simply inherited from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Remove width: 100%.

```
.fullwidth-blue {
  background-color: #8b9694; 
 }
.topBgColor {
   background-color:#9ACFD7; 
   padding:15px;
   border-bottom: 5px solid red;
   height: 70px;
   line-height: 70px;
}
.margin-bottom-10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Also you shouldn't be giving the `bg color` to the `row` but rather to a wrapping `div`. And the `image` shouldn't be put inside a `row` but inside a `col` as [the structure is container > row > col](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/). Last but not least, the `image` in **latest boostrap** has a [class to make it centered](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/images/).

```
<div class="fullwidth-blue">
  <div class="topBgColor">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
           <h3 class="text-center">Sign up for the LPP weekly newsletter here today!</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
            <img src="..." class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-10">...</div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-10">...</div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-10">...</div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```